# Combine columns from different tables with condition and AVG

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm practicing with SQL and I'm trying to achieve a query that came in my mind today.
I have three tables:

```
AUTHORS
AU_ID  NAME  LASTNAME  PHONE  ADDRESS  CITY  STATE  ZIP  CONTRACT

TITLES
TIT_ID  TITLE  TYPE  PUB_ID  PRICE  ADVANCE  ROYALTY  ...

TITLEAUTHOR
AU_ID  TIT_ID  AU_ORD  ROYALTYPER
```

What I want is to extract unique names and lastnames of authors and their respective AVG (average) price of books.

I tried a lot of stuff but I'm not able to achieve this.

Something that works, for now, is:

```
SELECT AVG(titles.price) FROM titles
INNER JOIN titleauthor ON titles.tit_id = titleauthor.tit_id
GROUP BY titleauthor.au_id
```

It gives me the AVeraGe price of authors books, but I don't know how to combine it with their names.

Comment: Show us some sample table data, and the expected result. (All as formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` again.

Comment: inner join to the Authors table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another join to the `author` table

```
SELECT [NAME], LASTNAME, AVG(titles.price) 
FROM titles
INNER JOIN titleauthor 
    ON titles.tit_id = titleauthor.tit_id
INNER JOIN author 
    ON author.AU_ID=titleauthor.AU_ID
GROUP BY titleauthor.tit_id, [NAME], LASTNAME
```

Comment: For completness you should add LastName as OP mention.

Comment: Damn, it was so simple... I still have to understand the logic here. Thank you man!